# Can class conflict cause "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError"?

Tags: maven, nosuchmethoderror

In my maven project, there were two different jars but contain the same class with the same package name. Can that cause NoSuchMethodError?
I know if the method does't exist will cause this Error? What if there have the method, but duplicate?

Comment: for same class you can use 

mypkg.classA a=new mypkg.classA();

mypkg1.classA =new mypkg1.classA();

Comment: How could you have different jars with the same package and the same classes? How could that happen? Made yourself

Comment: Yes when you compile against one version of a class and use another one, NSME can happen.

Comment: how this happens is very normal. 
consider A.jar is very feature rich library.
someone tried to extend functionalty of A.jar by adding some extra code.
he created B.jar . now B.jar has => some classes of A.jar.
now i need both B.jar and A.jar because B.jar has only few classes of A.jar
but cant import both B.jar and A.jar because same package name.

Comment: for example- smali.jar  and apktool.jar.
in current project i need both and i am here.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have two versions of the same project on the classpath and they changed the API. Depending on which JAR is looked at first, the method will be found or not.

If the method exists in both JARs, then it will work but something else might fail (there will be other differences).

If you add the same JAR several times on the classpath, then it will always work.

Solutions:

- Always make sure the classpath is clean. Every fully qualified class name should resolve to a single class resource (file).
- Sometimes, people add classes from different projects to their JARs "to make them easier to use." If that is the case, then open the JAR with a ZIP tool and delete the extra classes. Maven works better without such "help".

Comment: Just the case: people add classes from different projects to their JARs "to make them easier. And our component

Comment: - have to use their component JAR(A) and the source jar(B : which their pull some file). After carefully look, though the two file are similar but still little difference. Now I am trying to use a latest version of B(which file are the same as A), hope that can solve my problem. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: At last, we remove the dependency of B jar, and solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the conflict exists, and the method exists in both classes, the error won't show, however its a common case that there's a difference in a signature, between the conflicting versions, which can confuse you. My advice, check if the signature of the loaded class matches, and work your exclusions properly